# jQuery Datatable not responsive ordering to bottom after hidding column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables that have this simple structure:

```
<table id="tableListUsers" class="table table-hover dt-responsive compact" style="width:95%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>uid</th>
      <th><%= pageInfo.firstName %></th>
      <th><%= pageInfo.lastName %></th>
      <th><%= pageInfo.username %></th>
      <th><%= pageInfo.phone %></th>
      <th><%= pageInfo.address %></th>
      <th><%= pageInfo.jobDescription %></th>
      <th><%= pageInfo.active %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
    <tr>
      <td class="uidTable"> <%= user.uid %> </td>
      <td class="uidTable"><%= user.name %></td>
      <td class="uidTable"><%= user.lastName %></td>
      <td class="uidTable"><%= user.email %></td>
      <td class="uidTable"><%= user.phone %></td>
      <td class="uidTable"><%= user.address %></td>
      <td class="uidTable"><%= user.jobDescription %></td>
      <td class="uidTable"><%= user.active %></td>
    </tr>
    <% }) %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have hidden the first column because I only need the uid to edit the user shown but I dont have to show it to the user. So I added this configuration to my datatable and it hides the first column as expected. But if I resize the window to mobile size it's actually being responsive but it doesn't reorder the missing columns to the bottom of the row.

I hope you can understand better with the next images:

First this is all the info shown in my table:

[image]

But when I resize to mobile the table doesn´t show all the columns:
[image]

The expected output is this:

[image]

As you can see the columns are missing and there's no way to see them in the second image, this is the config of my data table:

```
table = $('#tableListUsers').DataTable( {
  rowReorder: {
      selector: 'td:nth-child(0)'
  },
  responsive: true,
  "paging":   true,
  "ordering": true,
  "info":     true,
  "language": {
    "lengthMenu": "Displaying _MENU_ records per page",
    "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
    "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
    "infoEmpty": "No records available",
    "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
  },
  // If I delete columnDefs it works as expected but I need it to hide the column 0 that I mentioned the user won't see.
  columnDefs: [
    { targets: [ 0 ],
    className: "hide_column"
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Have you try to use 100% on table width and may be you can see with chrome dev tools (simulating mobile version) if the data exists and are just hidden or for some reason they are non drawed by datatables

Comment: I just tried that, but no luck. I found out that If I set the uid td to be the last in the table this won't happen but it wont hide the column on mobile.

Comment: please change responsive: true to "responsive" : true, 
and to hide a column use "targets": [ 0 ], "visible": false on columnDefs

Comment: using visible: false from data tables worked! Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are hiding the column using a CSS class...

You should use the [DataTable's visible option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible).

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "visible": false, "targets": 0 }
  ]
});
```

Comment: This worked, I had used this but didn't work at the start, wonder what I did wrong there. Thanks for your time!

Comment: you just have wrong syntax, if you want to use your own class for hide a column or else you can use but please refer to datatables standart here: 
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.className